# Compile error '@material-ui/core' does not contain an export named 'makeStyles' after Material-ui-pickers installation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I need to use the inlineDatePicker components provided here by Material UI pickers: https://material-ui-pickers.dev/getting-started/installation

I ran the `npm -i` command however when I try to compile my code I get this error:

```
Failed to compile.

./node_modules/material-ui-pickers/dist/material-ui-pickers.esm.js
577:16-26 '@material-ui/core' does not contain an export named 'makeStyles'.
```

what? am I missing something? how do I get around this?

EDIT: 
So checking below, I checked the version and It gave me this error:

```
 peer dep missing: @material-ui/core@^4.0.0-alpha.7, required by material-ui-pickers@3.0.0-alpha.2
```

so I did `npm -i` @material-ui/core@^4.0.0-alpha.7

and now I get another compile error...

```
 '@material-ui/core' does not contain an export named 'createStyles'.
```

Is there a version of @material-ui/core that I can install that will stop this madness?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for testing v3 version of material-ui-pickers.
You need also to install new `@material-ui/styles` package. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/2xo3wmolmn) is working codesandbox.

Also, make sure that you read the [migration guide](https://next.material-ui-pickers.dev/guides/upgrading-to-v3) for v3.

Answer (score 1):

I have just faced with the same problem when I use following versions:
   "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
   "material-ui-pickers": "^3.0.0-alpha.2"

To fix compilation error I just downgraded version of material-ui-pickers to "^2.2.4"  and looks like it works

Answer (score 0):

I have just faced the same problem.And then I noticed that I didn't import the full path of the `<Button/>`, maybe you can try this to replace the original one:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
```

but not:

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core';
```